# Slider does not drag in combination with IsMoveToPointEnabled behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I have IsMoveToPointEnabled on for my Slider, so when I click anywhere on the component the selector moves to my mouse. The problem is if I have this option on and click and hold the mouse down to drag the selector the selector doesn't move. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way is to subclass Slider:

```
public class CustomSlider : Slider
{
  public override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
      OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
  }
}
```

In which case your XAML would be:

```
<my:CustomSlider IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" />
```

For a more versatile solution that doesn't subclass Slider you can do it with an attached property:

```
public class SliderTools : DependencyObject
{
  public static bool GetMoveToPointOnDrag(DependencyObject obj) { return (bool)obj.GetValue(MoveToPointOnDragProperty); }
  public static void SetMoveToPointOnDrag(DependencyObject obj, bool value) { obj.SetValue(MoveToPointOnDragProperty, value); }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MoveToPointOnDragProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MoveToPointOnDrag", typeof(bool), typeof(SliderTools), new PropertyMetadata
  {
    PropertyChangedCallback = (obj, changeEvent) =>
    {
      var slider = (Slider)obj;
      if((bool)changeEvent.NewValue)
        slider.MouseMove += (obj2, mouseEvent) =>
        {
          if(mouseEvent.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            slider.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(mouseEvent.MouseDevice, mouseEvent.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left)
            {
              RoutedEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
              Source = mouseEvent.Source,
            });
        };
    }
  });
}
```

You would use this attached property on Slider along with the IsMoveToPointEnabled property:

```
<Slider IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" my:SliderTools.MoveToPointOnDrag="True" ... />
```

Both of these solutions work by converting PreviewMouseMove events into equivalent PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown events whenever the left button is down.

Note that the attached property does not remove the event handler when the property is set to false.  I wrote it this way for simplicity since you almost never would need to remove such a handler.  I recommend you stick with this simple solution, but if you want you can modify the PropertyChangedCallback to remove the handler when NewValue is false.

Comment: Thanks Ray! I think I almost have it working. I'm having an issue with type casting in the mouse move function in SliderTools. Here's my error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler' to type 'System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler'. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry about that.  For the routed event technique I needed to pass in a MouseButtonEventArgs instead of a MouseEventArgs because the MouseEventArgs actually checks its event type.  I've made the necessary change and tested the resulting code.  It seems to do exactly what you want.  Enjoy!

Comment: Nice! However, if you click outside of the slider and drag into it, a drag is still initiated. If you have two sliders near each other, this sometimes causes an unintentional change to one.

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by Ray Burns Answer, the most simple way I found is this:

```
mySlider.PreviewMouseMove += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        mySlider.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(args.MouseDevice, args.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left)
        {
            RoutedEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
                 Source = args.Source
        });
    }
};
```

With mySlider being the name of my Slider.

There are two issues with this solution (and most others in this topic):
1. If you click and hold the mouse outside of the slider and then move it on the slider, the drag will start.
2. If you are using the slider's autotooltip, it will not work while dragging with this method.

So here is an improved version, that tackles both problems:

```
mySlider.MouseMove += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && this.clickedInSlider)
    {
        var thumb = (mySlider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", mySlider) as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Track).Thumb;
        thumb.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(args.MouseDevice, args.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left)
        {
            RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
                 Source = args.Source
        });
    }
};

mySlider.AddHandler(UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((sender, args) =>
{
    clickedInSlider = true;
}), true);

mySlider.AddHandler(UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((sender, args) =>
{
    clickedInSlider = false;
}), true);
```

clickedInSlider is a private helper variable defined somwhere in the class.

By using the clickedInSlider helper variable we avoid 1. The PreviewMouseButtonDown event is handled (because of MoveToPoint = true), so we have to use mySlider.AddHandler.
By raising the event on the Thumb instead of the Slider, we ensure that the autotooltip shows up.

Comment: Best version I've found so far for improved slider. I use it to create a more touch friendly slider. I found it cleaner to implement it in a subclass though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Binding to a mouse move event felt really wrong to me - I wanted a click on the slider to act like a click on the thumb so that the event only fires once and triggers normal dragging behavior. After doing some digging, I've come up with an alternative solution that works.

The Slider's `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` method is what handles changing the Slider's value when `IsMoveToPointEnabled` is `true`. However, the Thumb's `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` method is what handles grabbing focus, capturing the mouse, and then kicking off the `DragStarted` event. So the strategy I took is to have the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event on the Slider manually trigger the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event on the Thumb:

```
mySlider.AddHandler(
    PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        Track track = mySlider.Template.FindName("PART_Track", mySlider) as Track;

        // It's important to check `track.Thumb.IsMouseOver`, because if it's `true` then
        // the Thumb will already have its `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` method called - there's
        // no need for us to manually trigger it (and doing so would result in firing the
        // event twice, which is bad).
        if (!mySlider.IsMoveToPointEnabled || track == null || track.Thumb == null || track.Thumb.IsMouseOver)
        {
            return;
        }

        // When `IsMoveToPointEnabled` is true, the Slider's `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`
        // method updates the slider's value to where the user clicked. However, the Thumb
        // hasn't had its position updated yet to reflect the change. As a result, we must
        // call `UpdateLayout` on the Thumb to make sure its position is correct before we
        // trigger a `MouseLeftButtonDownEvent` on it.
        track.Thumb.UpdateLayout();

        track.Thumb.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left)
        {
            RoutedEvent = MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
            Source = track.Thumb
        });
    }),
    true);
```

We have to use the `AddHandler` overload that takes the third `handledEventsToo` parameter on the Slider to hook up our handler, as the Slider's `OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` method sets the event's `Handled` property to `true` when `IsMoveToPointEnabled` is `true`. Alternatively, we could subclass Slider and override it's `OnPreviewMouseLeftButton` method.

Comment: This worked for me, and here is the cleaned up and easier to paste version: https://pastebin.com/4yrjsQAg Just call that in your main window constructor, or something, and rename "HueSpectrumSlider" to your slider.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the improved version of @TimPohlmann's answer.

this one raises `MouseButtonEventHandler` only once. although the thumb raises `DragDeltaEventHandler` internally on every mouse move. but I found it unnecessary to fire `MouseLeftButtonDownEvent` on thumb at every mouse move myself.

Also there is no need for helper variable.

This is implemented as behavior. `AssociatedObject` is the slider that this behavior is attached to.

XAML:

```
<Slider ...>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <slid:FreeSlideBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Slider>
```

Behavior:

```
public sealed class FreeSlideBehavior : Behavior<Slider>
{
    private Thumb _thumb;

    private Thumb Thumb
    {
        get
        {
            if (_thumb == null)
            {
                _thumb = ((Track)AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("PART_Track", AssociatedObject)).Thumb;
            }
            return _thumb;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseMove -= OnMouseMove;
    }

    private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released) return;
        if(Thumb.IsDragging) return;
        if (!Thumb.IsMouseOver) return;

        Thumb.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(args.MouseDevice, args.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left)
        {
            RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you need to add the "Interactivity" assembly for this to work, which isn't included by default.

Comment: Also, apparently using Behavior breaks the designer (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755407/xaml-designer-will-not-display-when-using-blend-sdk-behaviors, https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-765).  I think I'll avoid it...

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
    private void slider_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = e.GetPosition(slider);
        slider.Value = point.X;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need custom Slider and custom thumb. When you click in slider (not hit in thumb) -

   ```
   var hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, point);
   if (hitTestResult == null) return;
   var parent = hitTestResult.VisualHit.ParentOfType<Thumb>();
   if (parent != null) return;
   _customThumb.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
   ```

you can call in custom slider method, which call inside `OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)`

2. You can you standart Thumb and use Reflaction for calling `OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)`